# Soundproofing tape outdoor

Tags: sound-proofing, railing, rain

I'm thinking about using soundproofing resilient tape on my balcony, mostly because rain sometime hits the metal railing and the noise bothers me.

I was wondering if such material is flame resistant, in other words, if there is a chance at all it might take fire when the weather is hot? Some claim FMVSS302 flame resistant, but I don't know what that means.

In addition, are there alternative to tape?

Comment: i think that the whole world would be constantly on fire if things caught on fire whenever it gets hot outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below explains what is the standard of "FMVSS302 flame resistant".

"FMVSS 302 Flammability of materials used in the occupant compartments of motor vehicles This standard specifies burn resistance requirements for materials used in the occupant compartment of motor vehicle. FMV SS 302 applies to passenger cars, multipurpose passenger vehicles，trucks，and buses."

So, if your material claims it meets the standard for use in a confined space (interior of cars), then it should be acceptable for your purpose for the concern of fire.

However, it sounds like a weird application on the railing. No other suggestion than to suggest changing the top rail from metal to wood.